# Find a recursive definition for inorder: binary Tree(T) → list(T ) where inorder(T ) is the list of nodes from an inorder traversal of T .

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees, binary

**Find a recursive definition for inorder: binary Tree(T) → list(T ) where inorder(T ) is the list of nodes from an inorder traversal of T .**

I have no idea what this question is even asking me. What the hell does -> list(T) even mean?

Comment: The line inorder: BinaryTree(T) -> list(T) is a specification of the inorder function. Basically it says that inorder takes a binary tree T as input and produces a list of nodes from an inorder traversel of T. However, your question is missing some context. In particular, we would need to know what the operation is to get the left and right subtree.

Comment: Ahh..This is all the information I was given unfortunately - so I'm really confused.

Comment: Suppose T.root, T.left and T.right means the root, left and right subtree respectively. Then the recursive definition of inorder(T) would be inorder(T.left) + list(T.root) + inorder(T.right) where the + is the list concatenation operator and list(T.root) returns a list containing the root node.

Comment: I'm not following.

Comment: First, do you know what an inorder traversal of a binary tree is?

Comment: Yes I understand what an inorder traversal of a binary tree is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the binary tree T below.

inorder(T) is a function that does an inorder traversal of a binary tree and collects the nodes in a list L in the order in which they are visited.

That is, inorder(T) returns a list L = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I]

Now, define T.root to be the root node of T. This would be F.

Define List(node) to be a list containing node.
That is, List(node) = [node]

Define T.left and T.right to be the left and right subtrees of T.
This would be the trees rooted at B and G respectively.

inorder(T.left) would return  L1 = [A, B, C, D, E]
inorder(T.right) would return L2 = [G, H, I]

Now a recursive definition of inorder(T) would be:

inorder(T) = inorder(T.left) + List(T.root) + inorder(T.right)

Hope that helps.

[image]